# I m getting this error while build sync "Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin

I Had done all possible solution. but still getting error

```
This is my Code Below
```

plese check this i m not finding any issue regarding my problem
and error is
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not determine artifacts for com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:17.1.0: No cached version available for offline mode

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username authToken }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}



appgraddle


buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'gradle.plugin.com.onesignal:onesignal-gradle-plugin:0.13.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'


repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        applicationId "com.rcloud.netflix"

        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "cd6a92d4-12c9-4692-bc90-3397c652e739",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]

        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "0.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/godel-release/godel/" }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'String', "PURCHASE_CODE", PURCHASE_CODE
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            buildConfigField 'String', "PURCHASE_CODE", PURCHASE_CODE
        }
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'server_url', server_url
    }
    compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'

    implementation 'com.github.rajan6533:Netflixlibjar:1.8'
    implementation 'ai.devsupport.instamojo:instamojolib:0.1.6'

    implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:8.0.1'

    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.3'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.4.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'

    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
//    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation('com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    }
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.16.1'
    implementation 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.2.2@aar'
    implementation 'com.github.siyamed:android-shape-imageview:0.9.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.ads.consent:consent-library:1.0.8'
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation 'com.mobsandgeeks:android-saripaar:2.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    implementation project(':bettervideoplayer')



    implementation('com.paytm:pgplussdk:1.3.3') {
        transitive = true
    }

    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:braintree:2.22.0'
    implementation 'com.braintreepayments.api:drop-in:'

    implementation 'com.mani:ThinDownloadManager:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.2.1'

//    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.leo.simplearcloader:simplearcloader:'

    implementation 'com.gauravk.bubblenavigation:bubblenavigation:1.0.7'

    implementation 'com.github.joielechong:countrycodepicker:2.3.3'

    // Required Dependency by Audience Network SDK
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.3.0'

    implementation 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.6.5'

    //new
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'androidx.mediarouter:mediarouter:1.2.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.16.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.16.0'

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:20.0.0'


    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.2.0'

    implementation "org.alfonz:alfonz-utility:0.9.1"
    implementation "org.alfonz:alfonz-view:0.9.1"

//    //Paykun
//    implementation 'com.paykun.sdk:paykun-checkout-lib:1.1.13'
//
//    //Traknpay
//    implementation project(':PGSDKVR4')


    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


please help me to get out for this error
```

Comment: Could you provide any recent changes you've made in the build configuration since this stopped working?

Answer (score 1):

Since the latest version of api-phone at time of writing is [17.5.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.android.gms/play-services-auth-api-phone/17.5.1) I suspect that you're not being able to retrieve it because you're still using deprecated jcenter().

You could first try replacing all "jcenter()" with "mavenCentral()".

Secondly you should consider if you really need api-phone? If not you could exclude the import from the play-service imports by adding something like:

```
  implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0") {
      exclude group: "com.google.android.gms", module: "play-services-auth-api-phone"
  }
```